# How to implement User Forgot Password in ABP.IO framework

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, abp

I have created ForgotPassword under IdentityServer4 Project: Pages > Account

However I don't seem to find any resource on how to implement Forgot Password

I can go and build the front-end using Razor but not sure how to back-end should be implemented

NB: I am using ABP as http://abp.io version 3.0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgraded to 3.1.2 should solve the issue